# Kivy transition between screens without transitioning navbar

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

Is there a way to transition between screens in a Kivy app while excluding a top navigation bar from the transition? The purpose of this is to have a "next screen" button and a "back" button of a top navbar remain in a fixed position between screens.

Comment: of coarse ...just have your frame with the navbar load the subscreens

Comment: I don't believe Kivy provides subscreens. Is there somewhere in the Kivy docs that mentions the use of subscreens?

Comment: oops your right ... no when I needed this we made a BaseScreen that autopopulated a title bar and called an `addBody` method then we defined each screen and subclassed our BaseScreen and then just had to define the addbody function ... its pretty painful actually ... sorry I jumped to soon on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your navbar in something like a vertical boxlayout. Also put your screenmanager in it. Now the screen changes will only affect the screenmanager. I used something like this in a Kivy talk at PyOhio 2014. [Code for slideshow app](https://github.com/brousch/pyohio-kivy-2014/blob/master/main.py#L232) and [Video of talk](http://pyvideo.org/video/2825/getting-python-all-up-in-your-mobile-with-kivy)